# Use ImageMagick in Unity MacOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick (latest version) with Unity on MacOS. I placed 4 dll in the Plugins folder :

- Magick.NET-Q16-x64.dll
- Magick.NET.Core.dll
- Ghostscript.NET.dll
- System.Drawing.Common.dll

In the script, I call `using ImageMagick;` and I did a little method to convert a .pdf file into a .png file:

```cs
public void Convertir(string pdf, string png)  {      
    MagickImage image = new MagickImage(pdf); //<-- the line causing the error (i guess by debugging)               
    image.Density = new Density(300);
    image.Write(png);   
}
```

When I use this method I get :

```
DllNotFoundException: Magick.Native-Q16-x64.dll assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
ImageMagick.Environment+NativeEnvironment.Initialize () (at /_/src/Magick.NET/Native/Helpers/Environment.cs:65)
ImageMagick.Environment.Initialize () (at /_/src/Magick.NET/Helpers/Environment.cs:21)
ImageMagick.MagickSettings+NativeMagickSettings..cctor () (at /_/src/Magick.NET/Native/Settings/MagickSettings.cs:321)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NativeMagickSettings' threw an exception.
ImageMagick.MagickSettings..ctor () (at /_/src/Magick.NET/Settings/MagickSettings.cs:33)
ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor () (at /_/src/Magick.NET/MagickImage.cs:42)
ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor (System.String fileName) (at /_/src/Magick.NET/MagickImage.cs:199)
ImportFile.Convertir (System.String cheminPdf, System.String cheminPng) (at Assets/Script/ImportFile.cs:136)
ImportFile.OnClick () (at Assets/Script/ImportFile.cs:68)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent/UnityEvent.cs:178)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/artifacts/generated/UnityEvent/UnityEvent_0.cs:57)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:70)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/Button.cs:114)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:57)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:272)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update() (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)
```

I searched on a lot of forums and these are too old or unanswered...

If someone could help me it would be handsome !